# ios using moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview

Okay so I'm making a to do list app. I'm just wondering how to use `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` properly since it keeps crashing if the `toDoItemCompleted` method is triggered. I'm trying to move a row down to the bottom of the list once the method is triggered.

```
-(void)toDoItemCompleted:(ToDoItem *)todoItem {
    NSUInteger origIndex = [_toDoItems indexOfObject:todoItem];
    NSIndexPath *origIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:origIndex];

    NSUInteger endIndex = _toDoItems.count-1;
    NSIndexPath *endIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:endIndex];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:origIndexPath toIndexPath:endIndexPath];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace

Comment: I don't get users down voting questions like crazy lately. I did how ever up vote maddy's answer which is correct you do not want to change your cells you want to update the source of the cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say what the error is. You should post the full error and point out which line of code is actually causing the error.

But one issue with your code is that you forgot to update your data source. This needs to be done before updating the table view.

Another issue is with how you create the index paths.

Something like this:

```
- (void)toDoItemCompleted:(ToDoItem *)todoItem {
    NSUInteger origIndex = [_toDoItems indexOfObject:todoItem];
    NSIndexPath *origIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:origIndex inSection:0];

    NSUInteger endIndex = _toDoItems.count - 1;
    NSIndexPath *endIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:endIndex inSection:0];

    // Update date source
    [_toDoItems removeObject:todoItem]; // remove from current location
    [_toDoItems addObject:todoItem]; // add it to the end of the list

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:origIndexPath toIndexPath:endIndexPath];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```